# Unable to convert datetime format to 00:00:00 instead of 12:00:00?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I know this might be duplicate but code is still not working for me in c#.

> I want to convert datetime format to 00:00:00 instead of 12:00:00

I tried like

```
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fromDate", dtFromDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
```

but not working for me :(

please correct me.

Comment: are you sure that the source datetime dtFromDate is midnight (12am) and not noon (12pm)? The format you have is correct

Comment: Why are you passing a date value as string? If you declare that `@fromDate` as `date`or `datetime` you can pass the value as DateTime. No conversion (by you) needed.

Comment: As per my answer below

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change  H:mm:ss instead of hh:mm:ss in the format string.

H represents the hour as a number between 0 and 23 , hh represents the hour as a number between 01 and 12.

```
dtFromDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss")));
```

i.e. it should look like:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fromDate", dtFromDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss")));
```

This will work.

Comment: For a two digit hour (00-23 rather than 0-23) OP will need 'HH'.

Comment: so can changing "HH" to "hh" solve the problem of making an hour 12:00:00 instead of 00:00:00?

Answer (score 1):

Using native datetime would be better practice I think

```
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fromDate", dtFromDate.Date)
```